# How do I change the coulour of the data points in a 3D Scatter Plot in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, 3d, scatter-plot

I'm having some trouble with a 3D scatter plot in R; it's been sometime since I used it significantly and it is the first time i'm working with the 3D plots.

My problem is in attempting to add colour to the two variables that define the plotted data points - the data is being read from a .csv file. In the code below I am able to produce a perfectly fine 3d scatter plot with all 195 data points in blue:

```
> with(sample, {
+    scatterplot3d(EXTRACT, ARRIVAL, PRICE, # x y and z axis
+                  color="blue", pch=19,    # filled blue circles
+                  type="h", lty.hplot=2,   # lines to the horizontal plane
+                  main="Extraction Dates for ORL",
+                  xlab="Extraction Dates",
+                  ylab="Arrival Dates",
+                  zlab="Price (EUR)")
```

When I attempted to add colour variation to the two variables I received the following errors:

```
> library(scatterplot3d)
> sample$pcolor[sample$COMP==WBSLON] <- "red"
Error in sample$pcolor[sample$COMP == WBSLON] <- "red" : 
  object 'WBSLON' not found
> sample$pcolor[sample$COMP==WBS6] <- "blue"
Error in sample$pcolor[sample$COMP == WBS6] <- "blue" : 
  object 'WBS6' not found
> with(sample, {
+    scatterplot3d(EXTRACT, ARRIVAL, PRICE, # x y and z axis
+                  color=pcolor, pch=19,    # filled blue circles on data points
+                  type="h", lty.hplot=2,   # lines to the horizontal plane; dashed lines
+                  main="Extraction Dates for ORL",
+                  xlab="Extraction Dates",
+                  ylab="Arrival Dates",
+                  zlab="Price (EUR)")
+ })
```

When I changed the WBSLON and WBS6 variables in the original .csv data column itself to 1 and 2 respectively, meaning:

```
sample$pcolor[sample$COMP==1] <- "red"
sample$pcolor[sample$COMP==2] <- "blue"
```

I receive no errors, however it simply produces a blank 3D plot - the plot area and axis labels but no data points plotted.

Is there a reason the code won't recognise the variables in text? And when I attempt to use numerical replacements in the data why do I get a blank plot?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @EDi Thanks for replying. Excuse my ignorance but could you explain what else you would need to see as a reproducible example? Are the code examples I provided not clear enough? Or do you need to see an example of the data also? Thanks

Comment: see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000. Yes, we need data and code, so we can just copy&paste on our machines.

Comment: @EDi, Sir, while constructing said reproducible, I realized that perhaps I was making a mistake in using "sample" as the name for my data, as this is clearly a function used by R.  On changing my data name to just "s1" in my code above (and using 1 and 2 in place of WBSLON and WBS6) worked and gave me the correct coloured output. Thank you for triggering my brain into a solution - a lot more time needs to be spent getting familiar again in R!!

Comment: If you found your own solution, please post it as an answer to close out the question so it doesn't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "sample" as the name for the data frame being used conflicts with R's use of Sample as a function.  The use of a different name that does not conflict with words already used by R allows the code to be read and executed successfully as written.